# Better alternative to pivot rows into columns

Tags: powershell

trying to stack these columns in powershell, and it works! however, it feels like there should be an easier way to do this. please let me know if you have alternatives that accomplish the same goal

```
$lines = @'
5 
b d7 e
c f
'@

$lines = $lines.Split("`n")

$max = $lines | % {$_.trim().split(' ').count} | sort -desc | select -f 1
$count = 0
$obj = New-Object psobject
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $count -Value $line
    $count++
}

for ($x = 0; $x -lt $count; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y -lt $count; $y++) {
        $obj.$y.trim().split(' ')[$x]
    }
}
```

desired output would be this:

```
5
b
c
d7
f
e
```

here's a more random example of input and desired output. the script:

```
$alpha = 65..90 | % { [char]$_ }
$lines = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $alpha.Count; $i ++) {
    $line = ''
    $cols = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 6
    for ($j = 0; $j -lt $cols; $j++) {
        $line += $alpha[$i+$j] + ' '
    }
    $line.Trim()
    $i = $i + $cols - 1
}

$lines = $lines.Split("`n")

$lines
# Rest of code same as above.
```

the first section shows the array. the second section shows what i want it to look like. (reminder: script already works, just looking for alternatives)

```
A
B C D E
F G
H I
J
K L M N
O
P Q R S
T U V W
X Y Z

A
B
F
H
J
K
O
P
T
X
C
G
I
L
Q
U
Y
D
M
R
V
Z
E
N
S
W
```

Comment: alright, @MathiasR.Jessen, show me what you've got!

Comment: Just to clarify can you show the desired output. Your input will always be a single string like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `$lines` is one of the here-strings you have above something like this would work just fine. Text coming from file would be just as easy to insert here.

```
$linesArray = $lines -split "`r`n" | ForEach-Object{,($_.Trim() -split '\s')}
$columns = ($linesArray | Measure-Object Count -Maximum).Maximum

$result = for($index =0; $index -lt $columns;$index++){
        $linesArray | Where-Object {$index -lt $_.Length} | ForEach-Object{$_[$index]} | Where-Object{![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)}
}
```

Where `$result` contains the "transposed" arrray. Split `$lines` into lines and for each line split on spaces (`Trim()`ed in case of trailing spaces which I found in your example).

Count the maximum columns so that we know how our loop will be structured. Then simply call the nth element of each line in order. Nulls are ignored so calling non exiting elements is a non issue.

Tested with PowerShell v4 but can be downgraded easy if need be. `$columns` is the only thing that would need to be changed.

---

I made a couple of changes to address comments. If a strict mode is enabled that flags accessing non-existent elements a simple where clause will prevent accessing those elements that do no exist. It also would be proper to address the nulls that are returned in case of post processing issues.

Comment: With `Set-StrictMode -Version 3` PowerShell produce `IndexOutOfRangeException` if you try to access not existing array element, so I would be add explicit array length check.

Comment: And without strict mode your code produce many `$null` values in the `$result`.

Comment: @PetSerAl both easy things to address I suppose. Just trying to keep it terse. I see the array addressing as a feature. Silly nulls

Comment: @PetSerAl I think that should cover it.

Comment: IMHO, `Where-Object {$index -lt $_.Length}` before `ForEach-Object` is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines=@'
5
b d7 e
c f
'@ -split "`r`n" 

$delimiter=' '
$max=-1
$xform=[ordered]@{}
$lineCount=0

foreach($line in $lines) {    
    $lineCount++
    $key="line$($lineCount)"

    $parts = @($line.trim().split($delimiter))
    $xform.$key = $parts

    if($parts.count -gt $max) {$max=$parts.count}
}

foreach($idx in 0..($max-1)) {    
    foreach($key in $xform.Keys) {
        $xform.$key[$idx]
    }
}
```